# How to make mutexes work in NDK on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, c++, c++11, ubuntu, android-ndk

Gradle experimental plugin v.0.7.0 is used to work with NDK in Android project.

For app module with native code this NDK configuration is used:

```
ndk {
        moduleName = 'engine'                                      
        toolchain  = 'clang'
        cppFlags.addAll(["-I${file(project.mPathIncOCV)}".toString(), 
                         '-O3',                                       
                         '-std=c++11',                               
                         '-frtti',                                   
                         '-fexceptions'])                          
        ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log', 'opencv_java3'])            
        stl = 'gnustl_static'  
    }
```

Everything works great with such configuration. Some std includes also work.

But. When I try to use mutexes (from std) in my C++ code, it works well in OS X, but encounters next error in Ubuntu which makes compilation impossible:

*'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type*

Looked for some corresponding questions. Tried to change stl on c++ and stlport, to use another (gcc) toolchain, but without any success.

Is it reasonable to keep trying to configure mutexes for compilation in Ubuntu, or it's better to look for some workaround (e.g. using mutexes from some library)?

Comment: boost library is what I would use for threading/mutexes. May be worth an implementation.

Comment: @M4rc I'll try to connect boost to my project. hope that ndk won't show any surprises with configuring it..

Comment: Perhaps you've run into [this bug](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/81)? The fix would be to define  `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS`

Comment: @Michael your suggestion is true and has fixed my problem, thank you! The problem was in usage of NDK 12 on laptop with Ubuntu (I thought that there was r11c version before I have checked it). After revert to r11c mutexes work.
But it's still interesting for me, where should we define _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS - in jni files? What content should we use for it?

Comment: You could just add `-D_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` to your `cppFlags`.